# openCl path tracer creates strange noise patterns

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, raytracing

I've made a path tracer using openCl and c++, following the basic structure in this tutorial: http://raytracey.blogspot.com/2016/11/opencl-path-tracing-tutorial-2-path.html. As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong with the path tracing algorithm itself, but I get strange stripe patterns in the image that don't match the regular noise of path tracing. [striped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqSq8.png)

There are distinct vertical stripes and more narrow horizontal ones that make the image look granular regardless of how many samples I take per pixel. Again, pixel by pixel, the path tracer seems to be working (the outlines of objects are correct even where they appear mid-stripe) as seen here: [close-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hROLN.png).

The only difference between my code and the one in the tutorial I link is that Sam Lapere appears to be using the c++ wrapper for openCl, and I've added a couple of features like movement. There also are a few differences in how I'm handling light bounces.

I'm new to openCl. What could be causing this? It seems like it doesn't have to do with my ray tracer itself, but somehow in the way I'm implementing openCl. I'm also using an SDL texture and renderer to show the image to the screen

here is the tracer code if it helps:

kernel:

```
__kernel void render_kernel
(__constant struct Sphere* spheres, const int width, const int height, 
const int sphere_count, __global int * output, __global float3* 
pixel_buckets, __global int* counter, __constant struct Ray* camera, 
__global bool* reset){

int gid = get_global_id(0);

//for movement
if (*reset){
    pixel_buckets[gid] = (float3)(0,0,0);
    counter[gid] = 0;
}

int xcoord = gid % width;
int ycoord = gid / width;

struct Ray camray = createCamRay(xcoord, ycoord, width, height, counter[gid], camera);

float3 final_color = trace(spheres, &camray, sphere_count, xcoord, ycoord);

counter[gid] ++;

//average colors
pixel_buckets[gid] += final_color;
output[gid] = colorInt(clampColor(pixel_buckets[gid] / counter[gid]));


}
```

trace:

```
float3 trace(__constant struct Sphere* spheres, struct Ray* camray, const int sphere_count,
         unsigned int seed0, unsigned int seed1){

struct Ray ray = *camray;

struct Sphere sphere1;
sphere1.center = (float3)(0, 0, 3);
sphere1.radius = 0.7;
sphere1.color = (float3)(1,1,0);

const int bounce_count = 8;
float3 colors[20];
float3 emiss[20];

for (int bounce = 0; bounce < bounce_count; bounce ++){

    int sphere_id = 0;
    float hit_distance = intersectScene(spheres, &ray, &sphere_id, sphere_count);
    struct Sphere hit_sphere = spheres[sphere_id];
    float3 hit_point = ray.origin + (ray.direction * hit_distance);

    float3 normal = normalize(hit_point - hit_sphere.center);
    if (dot(normal, -ray.direction) < 0){
        normal = -normal;
    }

    //random bounce angles
    float rand_theta = get_random(seed0, seed1);
    float theta = acos(sqrt(rand_theta));
    float rand_phi = get_random(seed0, seed1);
    float phi = 2 * PI * rand_phi;

    //scales the tnb vectors
    float x = sin(theta) * sin(phi);
    float y = sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    float n = cos(theta);

    float3 hemx = normalize(cross(ray.direction, normal)) * x;
    float3 hemy = normalize(cross(hemx, normal)) * y;
    normal = normal * n;

    float3 new_ray = normalize(hemx + hemy + normal);

    ray.origin = hit_point + (normal * EPSILON);
    ray.direction = new_ray;

    colors[bounce] = hit_sphere.color;
    emiss[bounce] = hit_sphere.emmissive;

}

colors[bounce_count] = (float3)(0,0,0);
emiss[bounce_count] = (float3)(0,0,0);
for (int i = bounce_count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    colors[i] = (colors[i] * emiss[i]) + (colors[i] * colors[i + 1]);
}
return colors[0];

}
```

random number generator:

```
float get_random(unsigned int *seed0, unsigned int *seed1) {

/* hash the seeds using bitwise AND operations and bitshifts */
*seed0 = 36969 * ((*seed0) & 65535) + ((*seed0) >> 16);
*seed1 = 18000 * ((*seed1) & 65535) + ((*seed1) >> 16);

unsigned int ires = ((*seed0) << 16) + (*seed1);

/* use union struct to convert int to float */
union {
    float f;
    unsigned int ui;
} res;

res.ui = (ires & 0x007fffff) | 0x40000000;  /* bitwise AND, bitwise OR */
return (res.f - 2.0f) / 2.0f;
```

}

thanks

Comment: You don't mention at all how you generate your random numbers. When it comes to looking for the cause of patterns in the noise, the random number generation would seem like an obvious suspect. You seem to be using some mysterious `get_random()` function. How does it work?

Comment: sorry, the get_random() function comes from the tutorial i linked. I'll include it above.  I assumed that it was not the culprit because I didn't modify it, and the tutorial produced clear pictures.

Comment: According to your edit, your `get_random()` function wants pointers to the two seed values so that it can update them. However, the code of your `trace()` function you posted calls `get_random()` passing it two `unsigned int` by value. I'm not an expert when it comes to OpenCL, but that would seem a bit weird to me; how does this even compile!?